# How to play my own server videos with vimeo player without uploading?

Tags: api, vimeo, video-player

I would like to play my own server video files (any type video) using vimeo player.
Is that possible. If I put a video URL, for ex: "http://www.myownserver.com/videos/test.mp4", I want to play this video on vimeo player.

In a single word, my video files requires a vimeo player and its features.

Comment: I have checked and research it long back, I guess the answer is NO. You can only embed the vimeo video code (embed or iframe).